# Webpack: Not every css style property is applied or working

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, twig, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a Symfony 6 Project together with Twig and Tailwind CSS.

I installed everything regarding this guide here:
**https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/symfony**

I am capable to use (some) tailwind css elements, my Webpack Encore loads through PostCSS the needed tailwind configurations and builds the assets under public/build/ directory.

 The base.html.twig loads the build assets

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            {% block title %}Welcome!
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <link
        rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('method2') }}


        {% endblock %}


    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

so I can finally use them inside index.html.twig (which extends the base.html.twig)

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}


{% block title %}
    Movies Page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="bg-blue-500 text-2xl text-center font-bold">
        {% for movie in movies %}
            <li>{{movie.title}}</li>
            <p class="animate-ping">{{movie.releaseYear}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <img class="p-1 bg-white border rounded max-w-sm" src="{{asset('images/image1.jpg')}}"/>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I try to apply tailwind properties on an example header and image.
However, the tailwind css properties regarding the header are working, but not for the image. Inspecting this inside the browser also doesn't show me the css values for given properties. I want my image smaller and framed with a border like here:

[image: how it should look like]
This is the result:
[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue: It was related to the path of the actual image.

Before it was stored under `assets/images/image1.jpg`

And I used it inside the twig template like so:

```
<img class="p-1 bg-white border rounded max-w-sm" src="{{asset('images/image1.jpg')}}"/>
```

Now, I used the `.copyFiles()` Function of Webpack Encore to store the images under `public/build/images`

webpack.config.js

```
.copyFiles({
    from: "./assets/images",
    to: "images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]",
    //uses regex pattern    
    pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
  })
```

now, when I address it from the public build path (regardless of hash) it is working:

```
<img class="max-w-full h-auto rounded-full" src="{{asset('/build/images/image1.c3b846ce.jpg')}}"/>
```

[image: example]

I guess this was somehow webpack related in some asnychronous processes. I will edit the question.